# Does AWS Lambda support Jython?

Tags: aws-lambda, jython

I have an application which is in Java8. I am trying to replace Java8 with Python, but my Java application have dependency which is in Java. So I can use Jython, right? If not, Could you please let me know, How can I implement?

Answer (score 1):

Some of the most popular JVM languages, other than Java, are Clojure, Groovy, Scala, Kotlin, JRuby, and Jython.

You can compile and subsequently run all these languages on AWS Lambda.

See: [Kotlin and Groovy JVM Languages with AWS Lambda | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/kotlin-and-groovy-jvm-languages-with-aws-lambda/)